# Irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{so}(4)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> I am supposed to give a 9-dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{so}(4)$.

I know that $\mathfrak{so}(4)\cong\mathfrak{so}(3)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and hence I have a 6-dimensional reducible representation of $\mathfrak{so}(4)$. But how do I get a irreducible 9-dimensional representation? 
This may be a stupid question but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: See [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPA_1971__15_1_15_0.pdf), section $2$.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't make head nor tail of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: The space of $4\times 4$ symmetric traceless matrices is of dimension $9$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1219061)

Comment: Why symmetric matrices? The Lie algeba is defined as traceless antisymetric matrices, isn't it?

Comment: @clearseplex while $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ is the space of antisymmetric matrices, the representation is on symmetric traceless matrices.  Remember the defining representation of $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ is 4-dimensional, and it induces a representation on the space of all $4\times 4$-matrices.

Comment: @nmasanta it answers the question if the OP is familiar with tensor product of representations.  I'm not sure what you are objecting.

Comment: @nmasanta The OP didn't provide any information on his level of knowledge, so an answer has to assume a suitable level. From my point of view, it is perfectly OK to assume knowledge about tensor products of reps, dual reps, etc, for a question like that. Even if the answer is beyond OP's knowledge, it is still valuable for others. What you are saying is basically like including a definition of prime numbers in a discussion on Riemann hypothesis, so that anyone can understand.

Comment: @nmasanta oh, so why not assume "everyone" doesn't know what a representation is, nor what $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ are, etc.?  Afterall, there are middle-school pupils on this site and that is a reasonable definition of "everyone", right?  I believe familiarity with representation of finite groups should be assumed before studying representation of Lie groups/Lie algebras.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this representation is irreducible? $\mathfrak{so}_4$ is not simple, and the defining representation is reducible.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The defining representation on $V=k^4$ is irreducible.  The reducible representation giving the $\mathfrak{so}(4)\cong\mathfrak{so}(3)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is $\Lambda^2V\cong\Lambda^+V\oplus\Lambda^-V$.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every treatment of representations of real semisimple Lie algebras explicitly treats the basic case $\mathfrak{su}_2$; the standard result is that for each positive integer $n$, there is up to equivalence exactly one irreducible $n$-dimensional $\mathfrak{su}_2$-representation, call it $\rho_n$.

Now if you already know $\mathfrak{so}_4 \simeq \mathfrak{so}_3 \oplus \mathfrak{so}_3$, and further know $\mathfrak{so}_3 \simeq \mathfrak{su}_2$, then let

$pr_1: \mathfrak{so}_4 \twoheadrightarrow \mathfrak{su}_2, \qquad pr_2: \mathfrak{so}_4 \twoheadrightarrow \mathfrak{su}_2$

be the projections on the respective factors. Then $\rho_9 \circ pr_i$ give two inequivalent (why?), irreducible (why?), $9$-dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{so}_4$.

Comment: Or you can use (3-dimensional irrep of first factor)$\otimes$(3-dimensional irrep of second factor), which is the irrep on traceless symmetric $4\times4$-matrices in my answer.

Comment: @user10354138: Ah, great. Actually I tried to see the connection to your answer, and got confused because there's a duality here that's missing there, but now I see.  Are these three all irreducible representations of dimension $9$?

Comment: Yes they are all there is, because irreps of direct sum are tensor products of irreps of factors.